# Outlook add-in to capture cancel meet event

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, yo

Is there any way we can capture the cancel meet event in outlook add-in Office js API or Custom event type?

I have scheduled a meet through third-party API for the outlook meet items so when the user opens and cancels the meet in the outlook I want to cancel the meet to the third party, I am not able to find any event or call back where I can perform the actions.

Comment: Are you trying this in Outlook Desktop (Win32) or Outlook Mac or Outlook on Web?

Comment: Outlook web and Outlook Desktop (win32) both, I need this to work uniformly on any outlook client.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Do we have any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Currently the feature to capture cancel meet event, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on [our Tech Community Page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Is cancel meeting bug is resolved?

Comment: Ticket on Microsoft tech community https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/way-to-capture-cancel-meet-event-in-outlook-add-in/idi-p/2365477#M85